# Nested UL Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with nested UL's to work as a drop down menu. In the drop down I have another nested UL with LI's that are pragmatically generated so I don't know how many are going to be in their.

I was trying to set the height of the second UL on load so that I can put a border around the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
        <ul>
            <li>2a
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>2a1</li>
                    <li>2a2</li>
                    <li>2a3</li>
                    <li>2a4</li>
                    <li>2a5</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>2b
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>2b1</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                    <li>2b2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

        ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            /*float: left;*/
            width: 100px;
        }

            ul li:hover {
                background-color: #cc0505;
                color: white;
            }

            ul li ul {
                /*visibility: hidden;*/
                position: absolute;
                padding: 0px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                /*min-height:120px;*/
            }

            ul li:hover ul {
                visibility: visible;
            }

            ul li ul li {
                /*display: inline;
                float: left;*/
                color: black;
            }

                ul li ul li:hover {
                    background-color: white;
                    color: black;
                }

                ul li ul li ul {
                    border: none;
                    min-height:0px;
                }

                    ul li ul li ul li {
                        display: block;
                        /*float: none;*/
                    }

                        ul li ul li ul li:hover {
                            background-color: #cc0505;
                            color: white;
                        }
```

I have tried using  `$('ul ul ul').each` and `$('ul ul ul').next()` to loop through any UL on the third level but it only seems to be picking up the first occurrence.

A jsfiddle I set up with my code and a few attempts I have made to get this right. http://jsfiddle.net/kZ236/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, that height() always takes the height of the first element of the set, no matter what you do before calling that.

using `each()` together with a `Math.max` will work

http://jsfiddle.net/kZ236/3/

your code with next() didn't work as the ul didn't had a next element. `next()` is no iterator through the set of `$('ul ul ul')` but getting the next sibbling in the dom tree.

Comment: Thanks, I used this but I did need to add '$('ul ul ul').height(0)' to prevent the child UL being larger than the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav>li>ul').each(function(){
        var maxHt=0;
        $(this).find('.submenu').each(function(){
            var bottomPosition=$(this).height() +$(this).position().top
            maxHt= bottomPosition>maxHt ? bottomPosition : maxHt;
        });

        $(this).height( maxHt)
    })
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ236/4/)**</kbd>